# Download file from Spring Boot application in Docker Container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, download

I have a docker container running Spring Boot (Rest Service). When user calls endpoint, an Excel file is created and need to be downloaded to users local machine. When I run spring boot outside docker everything works as expected, however when the same Spring Boot runs in docker I get a error 500 error.

The Code below is what I use to download file:

```
    final File fileToDownload = new File(fileName.toString());
    final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);

    String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(fileName.toString());
    if (mimeType == null) {
        // Set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
        mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    }

    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setContentLength((int) fileToDownload.length());

    final String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    final String headerValue = String.format("download; filename=\"%s\"", fileToDownload.getName());
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    final OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

    final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;

    while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    in.close();
    outStream.close();
```

Comment: Please, add the error log.

Comment: Please share more details about the error you are getting, this will help the community to understand your use case and share the relevant solution. Feel free to refer StackOverflow Q&A guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please give more details. Whether excel download is the only API you are exposing? If not whether other APIs and end points are reachable from outside?